# android: WebViews with JavaScript, content disappearing onCreateOptionsMenu();

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-optionsmenu

I've got a program, with three webviews.  Each webview is JavaScript enabled, and has dynamically generated content (lists, icons, spinning animations, etc...).  Everything is fine and dandy there.

Now I want to add a copy and paste functionality, so that users can paste values from other activities to the clipboard, and then copy them into my activity.  I'd like to do this using the options menu - with a "Copy" and "Paste" option to appear.  The problem right now is that the HTML contents of my webview disappear when the menu button is pressed, no matter what method i use to create my options menu(i.e. onCreateOptionsMenu(), or using a onKeyDown() midstep to stop the webview from consuming the event) and whether I use .add or define the menu in XML.

Anyone have any idea why this would be happening?  Does the Menu cause some sort of onPause to be called which might cause the html to be unloaded?  Below is my code for menu making/loading my webviews etc...

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

   // menu.add(0, 0, 0, "test");
    menu.add("HELP");
    return true;
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // do your menu stuff here
       openOptionsMenu();

       return true;

    }
        else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // starting values for each spinner
    cur1Sel="Distance";
    cur2Sel="Inch";
    cur3Sel="Milimeter";
    // starting inp and outp vals
    inputValue = "";
    outputValue="";
    // init my constats from above...
    POINT = 98;
    CLEAR = 99;

    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"helv_bold.ttf");
    format= new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    // nab them application resrouces you banger you.
    res = getResources();
    // build ouor arrays for display purposes
    measure_array = res.getStringArray(R.array.measure_array);
    input_array = res.getStringArray(R.array.distance_array);
    output_array = res.getStringArray(R.array.dist_inches_array);
    // init measure abbreviation arrays, otherwise we get null pointers first round....
    measure_abbrevs = new String[1];
    measure_abbrevs[0] = "none";

    // build abbreviation resrouces
    input_abbrevs = res.getStringArray(R.array.dist_abbrev_array);
    output_abbrevs = res.getStringArray(R.array.dist_inches_abbrev_array);
    // Webviews For Each Spinner
    measure_spinner = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.measure_view);

    input_spinner = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.input_view);
    output_spinner = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.output_view);

    // this lets everyone know where we start....
    curMeasure="Distance";
    // Measurement Spinner
    measure_spinner.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    measure_spinner.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidSpinnerBridge(), "android");
    measure_spinner.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

   // measure_spinner.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false); 
    //input Spinner
    input_spinner.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    input_spinner.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidSpinnerBridge(), "android");
    input_spinner.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    //input_spinner.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.setId({2});");
    //output Spinner
    output_spinner.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    output_spinner.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidSpinnerBridge(), "android");
    output_spinner.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);


    // buttons!  weeee! Buttons!!

    // IMPORTANT.. WAIT AWHILE FOR THE WEBVIEW TO PREPARE< OTHERWISE RENDERING MIGHT FAIL.  Then load.

    input_spinner.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index_sp2.html");
    measure_spinner.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index_sp1.html");
    output_spinner.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index_sp3.html");
    measure_spinner.loadUrl("javascript:SpinningWheel.fixTheFuckingError();");



};
```